# Can I connect technic hub 88012 to remote 88010 directly?

Tags: technic, powered-up

My seven year old has got the Technic hub and remote, and we were expecting them to pair but they won't. Do we have to pair them via the app or can they pair directly?

Answer (score 3):

You can connect them directly using Pybricks (a 3rd-party firmware for the Technic hub).

There are some tutorials at: https://pybricks.com/projects/tutorials/wireless/remote-control

Using official LEGO software, you have to use an app as a relay between the two.